# How do these two definitions of $a{\implies}b$ agree with each other?

Tags: logic

Let $a$ and $b$ be WFFs.

One definition of $a{\implies}b$ one can often encounter is "if $a$, then $b$".

The other is ${\lnot}(a\,{\land}\,{\lnot}b)$.

How do these two agree with each other? For example, if $a$ is ${\exists}x:x<0$ and $b$ is ${\exists}{\emptyset}:{\lnot}(y\,{\in}\,{\emptyset})$ it's true that ${\lnot}(a\,{\land}\,{\lnot}b)$. On the other hand, it's not true that "if $a$, then $b$", because $b$ could still be true even if $a$ wasn't.

Comment: "if $a$, then $b$" will always be True if $a$ is False, i.e. if $a$ is False, you can't conclude anything about $b$, because it may be True or False

Comment: If we can't conclude anything about $b$. then how is it "true" and not "neither"?

Answer (score 0):

The sentence "if $a$ then $b$" is *not* considered violated in the case where $a$ is false and $b$ is true. Think of it as a promise. When you write $a \implies b$, then you're saying "If you can show me that $a$ holds, then I can promise you that $b$ also holds". If $a$ does not hold, then the promise is pointless, but still upheld (and thus considered a true statement) no matter the state of $b$.

Answer (score 0):

In classical logic, we can start from a language with only two *connectives*:

> $\lnot, \land$

and then introduce new ones through definitions, like:

> $a \to b$ stands for $\lnot (a \land \lnot b)$.

This abbreviation agrees on the "intended" meaning of $\to$: "if ..., then ...".

According to the usual truth-table, $a \to b$ is *false* exactly when $a$ is *true* and $b$ is *false*.

As you can easily check, in this case (and only this) also $\lnot (a \land \lnot b)$ is *false*.